# Android : Backstack behavior with 2 running application

Tags: android, stack

If i have two application first "APP1" with "3 activity(A1 , A2 , A3)" and second "APP2" with "4 activity(B1 , B2 , B3, B4)".How will the backstack store these activity if i do this. Launch APP1 - A1 -A2 - HOME BUTTON - Launch APP2 - B1 - B2 - HOME BUTTON - LAUNCH APP1 - A3.  Can anyone explain the stack contains.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. check this link has details with pictorial representation of tasks and back stacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Backstack handles each Activity separate.
In Your Example The Backstack works so :

App1 : A1-> A2 -> add to the Backstack (A2 is on the top of the stack of App1 now)

HOME

App2 : B1-> B2 -> add to the Backstack (B2 is on the top of the stack of App2 now)

HOME

Launch APP1 (A2 is visible) : A3 -> add to the Backstack(A3 is on the top of the stack of App1 now)

App1 : A3 | A2 | A1

App2 : B2 | B1

Comment: So do you mean to say that for every application launched a different empty backstack  is there to handle the activity of that application?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted to say